# Context Managers as a class vs. function?

Tags: python, function, class, contextmanager

I have been looking into Python's contextmanager (more specifically, Python 3's contextlib or its back ported contextlib2) as of late, and I was wondering what were the advantages/disadvantages writing them as a class vs. a function?

They both seem to function the same way and handle exceptions the same way. There's a lot of cool utilities like ExitStack(), but those utilities seem to be implementable in context managers written as classes or functions. Thus, I'm struggling to find a good reason as to why one would want to write context managers verbosely as a class when they can be written as a function and just slap on the contextmanager decorator.

Here's a trivial example I wrote to showcase both doing the same thing:

```
# !/usr/bin/python -u
# encoding: utf-8

from contextlib import contextmanager

# Function-based
@contextmanager
def func_custom_open(filename, mode):
    try:
        f = open(filename, mode)
        yield f
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        f.close()

# Class-based
class class_custom_open(object):

    def __init__(self, filename, mode):
        self.f = open(filename, mode)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.f

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.f.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Function-based
    with func_custom_open('holafile_func.txt', 'w') as func_f:
        func_f.write('hola func!')

    # Class-based
    with class_custom_open('holafile_class.txt', 'w') as class_f:
        class_f.write('hola class!')
```

Comment: If you want your context manager to be anything else in addition to a context manager, you can't use `@contextmanager`.

Answer (score 6):

if you don't need the "verbose" class using syntax, you don't need it, its that simple.

The reason both are present is that the way using  classes is the actual way context managers work in the language. Any object having an `__enter__` and an `__exit__` method in its class can be used as a context manager.

The way using `@contextmanager` and allowing one to declare context managers as functions  is just a practical utility in Python's standard library.  What the decorator yields is an object that have both methods nonetheless.

One case in which writting a context manager as a class may be more compact is when the object which is used as a context manager is also a class under your control, and then you can better integrate running `__enter__` and `__exit__` in its life cycle.  For example, it is not uncommon to see objects that can be used either as decorators or as context managers (`unittest.mock.patch` comes to my mind). It sounds just "magic" to the user, but the implementation is quite clear and well defined: in the class of such an object, the logic for it to behave as a context manager is on `__enter__`/`__exit__`, and the logic implementing the decorator behavior is on the `__call__` method.

Answer (score 0):

Function-based context managers are simpler and easier to read. This would be my first choice usually.

One reason for choosing class-based context manager is already stated above in @jsbueno's answer. That is, when you want it to be more than just a context manager.

Another reason to use class-based is when you allow your Context Manager to be subclassed and extended further.