# Pythonic way to compose context managers for objects owned by a class

Tags: python, contextmanager

It's typical to require for some task multiple objects which have resources to be explicitly released - say, two files; this is easily done when the task is local to a function using nested `with` blocks, or - even better - a single `with` block with multiple `with_item` clauses:

```
with open('in.txt', 'r') as i, open('out.txt', 'w') as o:
    # do stuff
```

OTOH, I still struggle to understand how this is supposed to work when such objects aren't just local to a function scope, but owned by a class instance - in other words, how context managers compose.

Ideally I'd like to do something like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, in_file_name, out_file_name):
        self.i = WITH(open(in_file_name, 'r'))
        self.o = WITH(open(out_file_name, 'w'))
```

and have `Foo` itself turn into a context manager that handles `i` and `o`, such that when I do

```
with Foo('in.txt', 'out.txt') as f:
    # do stuff
```

`self.i` and `self.o` are taken care of automatically as you would expect.

I tinkered about writing stuff such as:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, in_file_name, out_file_name):
        self.i = open(in_file_name, 'r').__enter__()
        self.o = open(out_file_name, 'w').__enter__()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *exc):
        self.i.__exit__(*exc)
        self.o.__exit__(*exc)
```

but it's both verbose and unsafe against exceptions occurring in the constructor. After searching for a while, I found [this 2015 blog post](http://www.tech-foo.net/composing-context-managers-in-python.html), which uses `contextlib.ExitStack` to obtain something very similar to what I'm after:

```
class Foo(contextlib.ExitStack):
    def __init__(self, in_file_name, out_file_name):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_file_name = in_file_name
        self.out_file_name = out_file_name

    def __enter__(self):
        super().__enter__()
        self.i = self.enter_context(open(self.in_file_name, 'r')
        self.o = self.enter_context(open(self.out_file_name, 'w')
        return self
```

This is pretty satisfying, but I'm perplexed by the fact that:

- I find nothing about this usage in the documentation, so it doesn't seem to be the "official" way to tackle this problem;
- in general, I find it extremely difficult to find information about this issue, which makes me think I'm trying to apply an unpythonic solution to the problem.

---

***Some extra context***: I work mostly in C++, where there is no distinction between the block-scope case and the object-scope case for this issue, as this kind of cleanup is implemented inside the destructor (think `__del__`, but invoked deterministically), and the destructor (even if not explicitly defined) automatically invokes the destructors of the subobjects. So both:

```
{
    std::ifstream i("in.txt");
    std::ofstream o("out.txt");
    // do stuff
}
```

and

```
struct Foo {
    std::ifstream i;
    std::ofstream o;

    Foo(const char *in_file_name, const char *out_file_name) 
        : i(in_file_name), o(out_file_name) {}
}

{
    Foo f("in.txt", "out.txt");
}
```

do all the cleanup automatically as you generally want.

I'm looking for a similar behavior in Python, but again, I'm afraid I'm just trying to apply a pattern coming from C++, and that the underlying problem has a radically different solution that I can't think of.

---

So, to sum it up: what is the Pythonic solution to the problem of having an object who owns objects that require cleanup become a context-manager itself, calling correctly the `__enter__`/`__exit__` of its children?

Comment: I would say the solution with ExitStack is quite Pythonic.

Comment: @BrenBarn: nice to know, but I'm still a bit scared about the fact that there's only one mention about this solution in a random blog, and not in the official documentation, for what I think would be a quite a common problem. That's what leaves me perplexed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you expect this to be in the official documentation.  In general the official documentation only documents how things work, not what they're used for.  There are tons of common problems whose solutions aren't explained in the official documentation.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083791/alternative-to-contextlib-nested-with-variable-number-of-context-managers) is a related question, where in a comment to his answer Martijn Pieters also suggests subclassing ExitStack for what looks like a related purpose.

Comment: __A context manager that is designed to make it easy to programmatically combine other context managers and cleanup functions, especially those that are optional or otherwise driven by input data.__ I feel like the docs suggest that the `ExitStack` solution is perfectly Pythonic.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think contextlib.ExitStack is Pythonic and canonical and it's the appropriate solution to this problem. The rest of this answer tries to show the links I used to come to this conclusion and my thought process:

**Original Python enhancement request**

https://bugs.python.org/issue13585

The original idea + implementation was proposed as a Python standard library enhancement with both reasoning and sample code. It was discussed in detail by such core developers as Raymond Hettinger and Eric Snow. The discussion on this issue clearly shows the growth of the original idea into something that is applicable for the standard library and is Pythonic. Attempted summarization of the thread is:

nikratio originally proposed:

> I'd like to propose addding the CleanupManager class described in http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/12447 to the contextlib module. The idea is to add a general-purpose context manager to manage (python or non-python) resources that don't come with their own context manager

Which was met with concerns from rhettinger:

> So far, there has been zero demand for this and I've not seen code like it being used in the wild.  AFAICT, it is not demonstrably better than a straight-forward try/finally.

As a response to this there was a long discussion about whether there was a need for this, leading to posts like these from ncoghlan:

> TestCase.setUp() and TestCase.tearDown() were amongst the precursors to__enter__() and **exit**(). addCleanUp() fills exactly the same role here - and I've seen *plenty* of positive feedback directed towards Michael for that addition to the unittest API...
>   ...Custom context managers are typically a bad idea in these circumstances, because they make readability *worse* (relying on people to understand what the context manager does). A standard library based solution, on the other hand, offers the best of both worlds:
>   - code becomes easier to write correctly and to audit for correctness (for all the reasons with statements were added in the first place)
>   - the idiom will eventually become familiar to all Python users...
>   ...I can take this up on python-dev if you want, but I hope to persuade you that the desire *is* there...

And then again from ncoghlan a little later:

> My earlier descriptions here aren't really adequate - as soon as I started putting contextlib2 together, this CleanupManager idea quickly morphed into ContextStack [1], which is a far more powerful tool for manipulating context managers in a way that doesn't necessarily correspond with lexical scoping in the source code.

**Examples / recipes / blog posts of ExitStack**
There are several examples and recipes within the standard library source code itself, which you can see in the merge revision that added this feature: https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/8ef66c73b1e1

There is also a blog post from the original issue creator (Nikolaus Rath / nikratio) that describes in a compelling way why ContextStack is a good pattern and also provides some usage examples: https://www.rath.org/on-the-beauty-of-pythons-exitstack.html

Answer (score 12):

Your second example is the most straight forward way to do it in
Python (i.e., most Pythonic). However, your example still has a bug. If
an exception is raised during
the second `open()`,

```
self.i = self.enter_context(open(self.in_file_name, 'r')
self.o = self.enter_context(open(self.out_file_name, 'w') # <<< HERE
```

then `self.i` will not be released when you expect because
`Foo.__exit__()` will not be called unless `Foo.__enter__()` successfully
returns. To fix this, wrap each context call in a
try-except that will call `Foo.__exit__()` when an exception occurs.

```
import contextlib
import sys

class Foo(contextlib.ExitStack):

    def __init__(self, in_file_name, out_file_name):
        super().__init__()
        self.in_file_name = in_file_name
        self.out_file_name = out_file_name

    def __enter__(self):
        super().__enter__()

        try:
            # Initialize sub-context objects that could raise exceptions here.
            self.i = self.enter_context(open(self.in_file_name, 'r'))
            self.o = self.enter_context(open(self.out_file_name, 'w'))

        except:
            if not self.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()):
                raise

        return self
```

Answer (score 6):

I think use a helper is better:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack, contextmanager

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, i, o):
        self.i = i
        self.o = o

@contextmanager
def multiopen(i, o):
    with ExitStack() as stack:
        i = stack.enter_context(open(i))
        o = stack.enter_context(open(o))
        yield Foo(i, o)
```

The usage is close to native `open`:

```
with multiopen(i_name, o_name) as foo:
    pass
```

Comment: Your first snippet exhibits the same bugs as the one I wrote after *I tinkered about writing stuff such as* (what if I get an exception while doing the second `open`?); also, why should I remember to `close()` stuff? It's just boilerplate code to write and to potentially get wrong; the point of context managers (and destructors in C++) is to do let this be handled automatically, regardless of how we are exiting the context.

Comment: I didn't considered that before. I'm thinking about it now. But your example using `contextlib.ExitStack` is still not a good idea as in this case, users have to use `with` statement or the instance they get has totally different behavior. For `close()` stuff, your point also makes sense. But "The Zen of Python" says "Explicit is better than implicit." And at least for me I will explicitly close underlying objects so that I know what I'm doing completely. Surely it's also OK to use `__enter__/__exit__` pair.

Comment: That example can be easily adjusted by moving the whole initialization in `__init__` instead of `__enter__`; in that case even using it "manually" (creation and explicit `close()`) works correctly ([example](https://ideone.com/Y6QNzm)).

Comment: As for the explicit is better than implicit, it all depends. Resources cleanup is one of those areas where the more automatic the better, as developers are notoriously bad at it, especially in a language with exceptions. It's not a chance that Python has automatic memory management, even if "explicit is better than explicit".

Comment: Yep it depends. And about your example, I write another [example](https://ideone.com/w57Pkk) which I think is closer to native `open` and simpler.

Comment: I notice there is still a bug in your example. When user manually create an instance, there is no place to call `__exit__`, so it will still leak if second `open` fails. And when use `with` statement, the `__enter__` will be called twice. It's OK in this simple example, but may cause potential problem in real task.

Comment: "I write another example...": ok, but the "open two files" was just an example. My point is how to compose *in general* many context managers in one "owner" context manager class automatically. "I notice there is still a bug...": I didn't check, but I wouldn't be surprised, and that's an extra point in favor of handling this whole mess automatically, since the more you handle it manually, the more you risk messing up in subtle ways.

Comment: Well, you can add several context managers in this example. It also close to official example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack

Answer (score 6):

As @cpburnz mentioned, your last example is best, but does contain a bug if the second open fails. Avoiding this bug is described in the standard library documentation. We can easily adapt the code snippets from the [ExitStack documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) and the example for `ResourceManager` from [29.6.2.4 Cleaning up in an `__enter__` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/contextlib.html#cleaning-up-in-an-enter-implementation) to come up with a `MultiResourceManager` class:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager, ExitStack
class MultiResourceManager(ExitStack):
    def __init__(self, resources, acquire_resource, release_resource,
            check_resource_ok=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.acquire_resource = acquire_resource
        self.release_resource = release_resource
        if check_resource_ok is None:
            def check_resource_ok(resource):
                return True
        self.check_resource_ok = check_resource_ok
        self.resources = resources
        self.wrappers = []

    @contextmanager
    def _cleanup_on_error(self):
        with ExitStack() as stack:
            stack.push(self)
            yield
            # The validation check passed and didn't raise an exception
            # Accordingly, we want to keep the resource, and pass it
            # back to our caller
            stack.pop_all()

    def enter_context(self, resource):
        wrapped = super().enter_context(self.acquire_resource(resource))
        if not self.check_resource_ok(wrapped):
            msg = "Failed validation for {!r}"
            raise RuntimeError(msg.format(resource))
        return wrapped

    def __enter__(self):
        with self._cleanup_on_error():
            self.wrappers = [self.enter_context(r) for r in self.resources]
        return self.wrappers

    # NB: ExitStack.__exit__ is already correct
```

Now your Foo() class is trivial:

```
import io
class Foo(MultiResourceManager):
    def __init__(self, *paths):
        super().__init__(paths, io.FileIO, io.FileIO.close)
```

This is nice because we don't need any try-except blocks -- you're probably only using ContextManagers to get rid of those in the first place!

Then you can use it like you wanted to (note `MultiResourceManager.__enter__` returns a list of objects given by the passed acquire_resource()):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    open('/tmp/a', 'w').close()
    open('/tmp/b', 'w').close()

    with Foo('/tmp/a', '/tmp/b') as (f1, f2):
        print('opened {0} and {1}'.format(f1.name, f2.name))
```

We can replace `io.FileIO` with `debug_file` as in the following snippet to see it in action:

```
    class debug_file(io.FileIO):
        def __enter__(self):
            print('{0}: enter'.format(self.name))
            return super().__enter__()
        def __exit__(self, *exc_info):
            print('{0}: exit'.format(self.name))
            return super().__exit__(*exc_info)
```

Then we see:

```
/tmp/a: enter
/tmp/b: enter
opened /tmp/a and /tmp/b
/tmp/b: exit
/tmp/a: exit
```

If we added `import os; os.unlink('/tmp/b')` just before the loop we'd see:

```
/tmp/a: enter
/tmp/a: exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 58, in <module>
    with Foo('/tmp/a', '/tmp/b') as (f1, f2):
  File "t.py", line 46, in __enter__
    self.wrappers = [self.enter_context(r) for r in self.resources]
  File "t.py", line 46, in <listcomp>
    self.wrappers = [self.enter_context(r) for r in self.resources]
  File "t.py", line 38, in enter_context
    wrapped = super().enter_context(self.acquire_resource(resource))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/b'
```

You can see /tmp/a is closed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you want to process certainly for file handlers, the simplest solution is just to pass filehandlers directly to your class instead of filenames.

```python
with open(f1, 'r') as f1, open(f2, 'w') as f2:
   with MyClass(f1, f2) as my_obj:
       ...
```

If you don't need custom `__exit__` functionality you may even skip nested with.

If you really want to pass filenames to `__init__`, your problem could be solved like this:

```
class MyClass:
     input, output = None, None

     def __init__(self, input, output):
         try:
             self.input = open(input, 'r')
             self.output = open(output, 'w')
         except BaseException as exc:
             self.__exit___(type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__)
             raise

     def __enter__(self):
         return self

     def __exit__(self, *args):
            self.input and self.input.close()
            self.output and self.output.close()
        # My custom __exit__ code
```

So, it really depends on your task, python have plenty options to work with. In the end of the day - pythonic way is to keep your api simple.

Comment: I think allocating resource in `__init__` is an anti-pattern, explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074847/catching-exception-in-context-manager-enter#comment137408538_58806222 .

Answer (score 0):

### Simplified solution using `contextmanager`

[Sraw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51650607/5267751) can be simplified as follows:

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, i, o):
        self.i = i
        self.o = o

@contextmanager
def multiopen(i, o):
    with open(i) as i, open(o) as o:
        yield Foo(i, o)
```

You don't need an explicit `ExitStack` in this case.

Of course, you can use it as follows:

```py
with multiopen() as foo:
    print(foo)
```

If the number of objects is not fixed, then it's still recommended to use `ExitStack` as shown in [Sraw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51650607/5267751).

> A context manager that is designed to make it easy to programmatically combine other context managers and cleanup functions, **especially those that are optional or otherwise driven by input data**.

### If you need the resulting object to be both a contextmanager and a class

Use case described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957756/5267751 .

For example you may want something like the following to work:

```py
@multiopen()
def f():
    ...

with multiopen() as foo:
    ...
```

For this, the object being returned by `multiopen()` must implement all of `__call__`, `__enter__` and `__exit__`.

The simplest solution is the following.

```py
@contextmanager
def _multiopen(i, o):
    with open(i) as i, open(o) as o:
        yield Foo(i, o)

class multiopen(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self, i, o):
        self._multiopen_instance = _multiopen(i, o)
    def __enter__(self):
        self._multiopen_instance.__enter__()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        return self._multiopen_instance.__exit__(exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
```

That is, still make a contextmanager, but **wrap over it with a [`ContextDecorator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator) class**.

Of course, this may looks ugly (you need the `@contextmanager` decorator, then immediately throw it away and make a class manually).
Actually, it's not that bad --- even the recipe in the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#cleaning-up-in-an-enter-implementation reduces a contextmanager.

### If you refuse to use `@contextmanager`

You can also use `pop_all` --- the core idea is that

> `pop_all` allows you to **break up a `with` block**.

This is exactly what you need to do in order to break the `with` block into the `__enter__` method and the `__exit__` method.

Like this: the code block

```py
with ExitStack() as stack:
    stack.enter_context(A(0))
    stack.enter_context(A(0))
    BODY
```

can be broken down such that `BODY` no longer remains in the `with` block as follows:

```py
with ExitStack() as stack:
    stack.enter_context(A(0))
    stack.enter_context(A(0))
    stack2 = stack.pop_all()
# at this point stack.close() is called, but it does not call __exit__ on any A object.

BODY

stack2.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

Of course, you still need to remember to handle the case `BODY` raises an error, so:

```py
with ExitStack() as stack:
    stack.enter_context(A(0))
    stack.enter_context(A(0))
    stack2 = stack.pop_all()
with stack2:
    BODY
```

So, as a class:

```py
class Multiopen:
    def __enter__(self):
        with ExitStack() as stack1:
            stack1.enter_context(...)
            stack1.enter_context(...)
            self._stack2=stack1.pop_all()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self._stack.close()
```

If any of the `__enter__` raises an error, `stack1` will unwind them.
If none of them raises an error, `self._stack2` will unwind them instead.

### If you want to implement it yourself

The complexity is not just with `ExitStack`, it is also with the `with` statement itself.

From the documentation:

> The following code:
>
> ```py
> with EXPRESSION as TARGET:
>     SUITE
> ```
>
> is semantically equivalent to:
>
> ```py
> manager = (EXPRESSION)
> enter = type(manager).__enter__
> exit = type(manager).__exit__
> value = enter(manager)
> hit_except = False
>
> try:
>     TARGET = value
>     SUITE
> except:
>     hit_except = True
>     if not exit(manager, *sys.exc_info()):
>         raise
> finally:
>     if not hit_except:
>         exit(manager, None, None, None)
> ```

So, if we want to make a class, of course we cannot use `with` statement.

I can't figure out how to implement this correctly yet.

- If the first object's `__enter__` raises an exception, then we must not call the first object's `__exit__`.
- However, if the second object's `__enter__` raises an exception, we must call the first object's `__exit__`.
- Furthermore, if the second object's `__exit__` raises an exception, we must proceed to continue to call the first object's `__exit__`.
- The first object's `__exit__` may, in turn, suppress that exception.

(In this context, the `open()` should be seen as the `__enter__`. It may be more idiomatic to write a contextmanager that represents a file.)