# Correct way to manage multiple resources with context managers

Tags: python, contextmanager

I have some resources which I have wrapped in a context manager class.

```
class Resource:
    def __init__(self, res):
        print(f'allocating resource {res}')
        self.res = res

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.res

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        print(f'freed resource {self.res}')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.res}'
```

If I were to use 2 resources directly, I could use the following syntax:

```
with Resource('foo') as a, Resource('bar') as b:
    print(f'doing something with resource a({a})')
    print(f'doing something with resource b({b})')
```

This works as expected:

> ```
> allocating resource foo
> allocating resource bar
> doing something with resource a(foo)
> doing something with resource b(bar)
> freed resource bar
> freed resource foo
> ```

What I'd like to do, however, is wrap the use of these multiple resources into a class `Task`, and make that itself a context manager.

This is my first attempt at creating such a `Task` class which manages 2 resources:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, res1, res2):
        self.a = Resource(res1)
        self.b = Resource(res2)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.b.__exit__(type, value, traceback)
        self.a.__exit__(type, value, traceback)

    def run(self):
        print(f'running task with resource {self.a} and {self.b}')
```

I can now use the familiar syntax:

```
with Task('foo', 'bar') as t:
    t.run()
```

And again this works as expected:

> ```
> allocating resource foo
> allocating resource bar
> running task with resource foo and bar
> freed resource bar
> freed resource foo
> ```

This all works fine, except when an exception is thrown trying to free one of the resources.

To illustrate I have modified my `Resource` class to throw an exception for one of the resources:

```
class Resource:
    def __init__(self, res):
        print(f'allocating resource {res}')
        self.res = res

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.res

    def __exit__(self, typ, value, traceback):
        print(f'try free resource {self.res}')
        if self.res == 'bar':
            raise RuntimeError(f'error freeing {self.res} resource')
        print(f'freed resource {self.res}')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.res}'
```

With the previous manual use of 2 resources:

```
try:
    with Resource('foo') as a, Resource('bar') as b:
        print(f'doing something with resource a({a})')
        print(f'doing something with resource b({b})')
except:
    pass
```

In the face of the exception freeing `bar`, `foo` is still freed:

```
allocating resource foo
allocating resource bar
doing something with resource a(foo)
doing something with resource b(bar)
try free resource bar
try free resource foo
freed resource foo
```

However, doing the same with `Task`, I leak the second resource:

```
try:
    with Task('foo', 'bar') as t:
        t.run()
except:
    pass
```

Output showing I never try free `foo`:

> ```
> allocating resource foo
> allocating resource bar
> running task with resource foo and bar
> try free resource bar
> ```

**Questions:**

- I could wrap each explicit call to `Resource.__exit__` in a `try`/`except` block, but then if I want to propagate the exception further up the call stack whilst still freeing up all the resources, I have to keep track of all exceptions and then rethrow them afterwards... it feels incorrect.
- It also feels "dirty" calling `Resource.__exit__` explicitly from `Task.__exit__`, rather than having the `with` statement call it implicitly for me. Is there a way to use a context manager *inside* a class like I'm trying to do?

What is the right way to handle multiple resources inside a single context manager?

Comment: The explicit try except is your best bet. You need to decide and document what you do when multiple exceptions are raised.

Comment: Take a look at `ExitStack`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack

Comment: @MadPhysicist `ExitStack` looks to be exactly what I'm looking for - thanks, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) does exactly this.

> A context manager that is designed to make it easy to programmatically combine other context managers

You can simply inherit from `ExitStack` and call `enter_context` for each resource you want managed:

```
class Task(contextlib.ExitStack):
    def __init__(self, res1, res2):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = self.enter_context(Resource(res1))
        self.b = self.enter_context(Resource(res2))

    def run(self):
        print(f'running task with resource {self.a} and {self.b}')
```

Note there is no need to define your own `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions, as `ExitStack` does that for us.

Using it as in the example:

```
try:
    with Task('foo', 'bar') as t:
        t.run()
except:
    pass
```

Now when the exception is thrown freeing `bar`, `foo` is still freed:

> ```
> allocating resource foo
> allocating resource bar
> running task with resource foo and bar
> try free resource bar
> try free resource foo
> freed resource foo
> ```

Comment: I see one problem. What if the exception is raised in __init__ where some of the resources already cretaed/opened. `__exit__` will not be called. Possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51788906/13782669)