# ExitStack within classes

Tags: python, class, printing, valueerror

I would like to understand why using the following snippet leads me to an error:

a) I want to use the following class to create a context manager, as outlined in the link attached below: for me it is **very important to keep the "class PrintStop(ExitStack)" form**, so please bear in mind when trying to solve this issue, that I already know there are other ways to use ExitStack(), but I am interested in this specific way of using it:

```
class PrintStop(ExitStack):
    def __init__(self, verbose: bool = False):
        super().__init__()
        self.verbose = verbose

    def __enter__(self):
        super().__enter__()
        if not self.verbose:
            sys.stdout = self.enter_context(open(os.devnull, 'w'))
```

b) when trying to use the class in the more appropriate way, I get the desired effect to stop all the printing within the "with" block, but when trying to print again after that block I get an error:

```
with PrintStop(verbose=False):
        print('this shouldn't be printed') <------ok till here

print('this should be printed again as it is outside the with block)  <-----ERROR
```

c) the error I get is "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file": the reason I guess is the fact that **exit** method of ExitStack() is not automatically called once we exit the 'with' block, so, how may I change the class to fix this bug?

Here is a quick reference to a similar topic,
[Pythonic way to compose context managers for objects owned by a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51649361/pythonic-way-to-compose-context-managers-for-objects-owned-by-a-class)

Comment: It's not that `ExitStack.__exit__` isn't called, it's that it *is* and what it does is close whatever `sys.stdout` refers to without restoring `sys.stdout` to its former value.

Answer (score 0):

`ExitStack.__exit__` simply ensures that each context you enter has its `__exit__` method called; it does *not* ensure that any changes you made (like assigning to `sys.stdout`) inside the corresponding `__enter__` is undone.

Also, the purpose of an exit stack is to make it easy to enter contexts that require information not known when the `with` statement is introduced, or to create a variable number of contexts without having to enumerate them statically.

If you really want to use an exit stack, you'll need something like

```
class PrintStop(ExitStack):
    def __init__(self, verbose: bool = False):
        super().__init__()
        self.verbose = verbose

    def __enter__(self):
        rv = super().__enter__()
        if not self.verbose:
            sys.stdout = self.enter_context(open(os.devnull, 'w'))
        return rv

    def __exit__(self):
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__  # Restore the original
        return super().__exit__()
```

Keep in mind that `contextlib` already provides a context manager for temporarily replacing standard output with a different file, appropriately named `redirect_stdout`.

```
with redirect_stdout(open(os.devnull, 'w')):
    ...
```

Using this as the basis for `PrintStop` makes use of composition, rather than inheritance.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, nullcontext


class PrintStop:
    def __init__(self, verbose: bool = False):
        super().__init__()
        if verbose:
            self.cm = redirect_stdout(open(os.devnull, 'w'))
        else:
            self.cm = nullcontext()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.cm.__enter__()

    def __exit__(self):
        return self.cm.__exit__()
```