# acquiring multiple context managers in an error safe manner

Tags: python-3.x, contextmanager

Will the code below safely acquires multiple FileLock context manager objects and also release all resources at any error in `__enter__`?

When using multiple context manager resources, the resource acquisitions must be atomic (all succeed or none succeed). With any error, all the resources that have been already acquired need to be released. Read [Pythonic way to compose context managers for objects owned by a class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792237/4281353) but it looks complicated, and would like to have simpler one. If there is better way, please suggest.

```
from contextlib import (
    ExitStack
)
from typing import (
    Sequence,
    ContextManager,
    Optional,
)



class MultiFileLocks:
    def __init__(self, filepaths: Sequence[str]):
        if filepaths is None or len(filepaths) == 0:
            raise ValueError(f"invalid filepath:[{filepaths}].")

        self._filepaths: Sequence[str] = [
            str(pathlib.Path(_path).expanduser().resolve()) for _path in filepaths
        ]
        self._stack: Optional[ExitStack] = None
        self._locks: Optional[Sequence[FileLock]] = None

    def __enter__(self) -> ContextManager:
        with ExitStack() as temp_stack:
            _locks = [
                temp_stack.enter_context(FileLock(_path)) for _path in self._filepaths
            ]
            self._stack = temp_stack.pop_all()
            self._locks = _locks

        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self._stack.close()
        self._stack = None
        self._locks = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks mostly fine, but you have one major issue to contend with. If the file locks are acquired in a blocking manner, and different `MultiFileLock`s are created with the same files to lock, in different orders, you can end up with a variation on [the Dining Philosophers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem).

The simplest solution to such an issue is to impose an ordering on your files, e.g. sorting them by canonical paths, so that all locks are acquired in a single partial ordering (there are flaws to this solution involving fairness, you can read more on the Dining Philosophers link for more advanced solutions).

As a more minor issue, unless you need access to the stack itself after `__enter__` returns, you could simplify things by just binding the `close` method alone, [per the example on `pop_all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack.pop_all) to avoid visibly storing the stack itself (it still stores everything, this just limits complexity from your point of view).

Otherwise you're looking good.

Comment: Thank you, the file lock is using ```fcntl.flock(self._file.fileno(), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)```, hence I believe it is not non blocking.

Comment: "avoid visibly storing the stack itself" means store ```close_files``` method instance instead of ```_stack``` and call it at ```__exit__``` as in 
> close_files() can then be invoked explicitly to close them all.?

Comment: @mon: Yep. There is nothing else you need the stack itself for, so you just store the bound `close` method (which does keep the stack alive, but it's even less part of your interface).